# C# Updating properties of LINQ result

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, properties

I have a list that is

```
public static List<registry> regs = new List<registry>();
    public struct registry
    {
        public int from;
        public int rows;
        public bool isValid;
        public DateTime date;
        public List<T> result;
        public bool ok;
    }
```

I'm getting a registry from regs using the following code:

```
registry x = regs.SingleOrDefault(p => p.from == from && p.rows == rows);

        if (x.isValid == false) //checking if its default
        {
            regs.Add(new registry() { ok = true});
            x = regs.Last();
        }
```

Then, i want to update that single value. I'm trying to simple update the value, but it isn't working.

```
x.isValid = true;
```

It is only updating X, not the list. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`registry` is a struct, so

```
registry x = regs.SingleOrDefault...
```

returns a copy of it, not a reference, and then you modify the copy.

Answer (score 0):

What you're updating is a different copy of that object, not the one in the list.
To edit the one in the list you can use the `List.Find` method and edit that one returned ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/x0b5b5bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: I've tried to use Find. Didn't work if I use struct.